# Object of type complex is not JSon serializable: ignore expressions burried in a string?

Tags: python, json, complex-numbers

So I have a massing csv dump that I need to parse to JSON. Among those csv fields, there are comment fields, similar to this one:

```
2999.99 + 90J
```

which I guess is meant as a price and a number of days, but then when I get to dumping this as JSON it shows up as

```
(2999.99+90j)
```

Which is a complex number and not json seriablizable. I guess I could try to find & replace all border cases, but I'd rather just tell json/python to ignore any complex number representation? Is there some way to do that? Or do I really need to go through all the data? A quick search tells me there are a least a few problematic comments like that, so I'd rather not....

Comment: Who is converting that to complex?  The `csv` module certainly doesn't do that.  It returns everything as strings.

Comment: I'm guessing json

Comment: No.  The Python JSON module does not do any type interpretation.  `csv` would read it as a string, and `json` would write it as a  string.  Something in your code is evaluating the string and converting it.  THAT'S what you need to chase down.

Comment: Oh, you may very well be right. I'm not doing a ton of processing on it, but some objects might be passing through some classes and maybe there's a step I'm not thinking about.... Will check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something in your code that is doing this conversion.  Here's how the standard modules work:

```
import csv
import json

# x.csv contains:
# one,two,333,444+44j,555

data = list(csv.reader(open('x.csv')))
print(data)

d = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[['one', 'two', '333', '444+44j', '555']]
[
    [
        "one",
        "two",
        "333",
        "444+44j",
        "555"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yup - turns out there was a part of the program somewhere that used literal_eval. Which obviously parsed it as a complex number, so that when it got json.dumps(...) it failed. Thanks for the idea.